# Java Object Oriented - Advanced Constructors Assistance ? :\

Tags: java, oop

Can someone please check my code and determine why my pickup function's not working.

-- write missing methods for these procedures to occur

- Dog bob = new Dog(5);
- System.out.println(bob);
- bob.walk();
- bob.walk();
- bob.pickUp("Tennis ball");
- System.out.println(bob);
- bob.drop();
- bob.bark();
- System.out.println(bob);

-- In my class where I've defined the pickUp method:

```
    public Head()
{

}

public void pickUp(String object)
{   
    this.object = object;
    System.out.println("Picked up "+object);
}

public String getObject()
{
    return object;
}

public void drop()
{
    System.out.println("Dropped "+object);
    object = null;
}

public void bark()
{
    System.out.println("WOOF!");
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Head is holding "+ object;
}
}
```

-- The other class where I'm utilising the method:

```
public class Dog
{
private int position;
private Leg hind1;
private Leg hind2;
private Leg front1;
private Leg front2;
private Head head = new Head();

//Constructor for Dog class
public Dog(int position)
{
    hind1 = new Leg(position-2);
    hind2 = new Leg(position-2);
    front1 = new Leg(position+2);
    front2 = new Leg(position+2);
}

public void walk()
{
    front1.step();
    front2.step();
    hind1.step();
    hind2.step();
    System.out.println("Pitter patter...");
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Head is holding " + head+", Leg at "+hind1.position+", Leg at "+ hind2.position+", Leg at "+front1.position+", Leg at "+front2.position;
}   

public void pickup()
{
    head.pickUp(head.object);
} 

public void drop()
{
    head.drop();
}

public void bark()
{
    head.bark();
}
```

PS. head is a new object I've made which belongs to the Head Class, Which is where the first code is from. I'm currently trying to get the second code working to display a picked up object that head picked up.

-EDIT : Even if I do put a string in(Eg. head.pickUp("ball");), it still displays "cannot find symbol - method.pickUp(java.lang.String)" when I try running the procedures.

Comment: How exactly is this "not working"? What is the type of `head.object`?

Comment: What's not working? This code always sets `object` to the same thing.

Comment: `head.pickUp(head.object);` tries to set the same object again. What is not working?

Comment: What is the expected output? what is the actual output?

Comment: Eg. If I run the second command, it does compile but somehow it says cannot find symbol  : method pickUp(java.lang.String)

Comment: Can you paste more code, please? Is not clear what the problem could be from the code you have already shown.

Comment: You class Head didn't have any method: `public Head(){ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED (a third time!): Now that you've posted your code, I've confirmed that my answer below is correct.  Tl;dr - you're trying to use head.object before it's been set.  What you should be passing in to pickUp is a string that represents the name of the object you want to pick up.  For example, head.pickUp("ball");

---

It would help if you could clarify a bit more what you mean by "not working" - however, it looks like you've got a sort of chicken-and-egg problem here:

If I'm reading this right, your code looks something like this? (Including the entire class in your comment might help)

```
public class Head {

   String object;

   public void pickUp(String object)
   {   
       this.object = object;
       System.out.println("Picked up "+object);
   }

}

public class SomeOtherClass {

   Head head = new Head();

   public void pickup()
   {
       head.pickUp(head.object);

   } 
}
```

EDITED (again) for clarity - It looks like you're trying to use the pickup function (the one in SomeOtherClass) to define the object property of your head.  However, by calling it with head.object, you assume that head.object is already defined.  Where are you actually setting the string you want to use?

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here - but you might want to try either 1) setting head.object in a constructor in your head class. or 2) calling head.pickUp with a string other than head.object (which hasn't been set yet). - Try replacing head.object with "Hello World", for starters. Or, if I've totally misunderstood your intent, perhaps give us a bit more context?

EDITED - because I realized that your pickup function wasn't in Head.

Comment: You also have a problem with your toString method in Dog - try it out, you'll see that it repeats "Head is holding" twice, once from Dog's toString and once from Head's - you should probably remove the "Head is holding" in Dog.

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming if I placed head.object, it'd place any of the requested String object to be working with the pickUp function.